# Send requests to sogo calendar

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, calendar, caldav

I'm currently really lost and need your help guys. The problem is quiet easy, but I'm not able to find anything useful on that. On my server I implemented SOGo. I now want to write an read events from a certraint calendar. Therefore, I use the libary tsdav. I can read events with the following code:

```
const client = await createDAVClient({
    serverUrl: 'https://example.com',
    homeUrl: 'https://example.com/SOGo/dav/username/',
    credentials: {
        username: username,
        password: password,
    },
    authMethod: 'Basic',
    defaultAccountType: 'caldav',
});

const calendars = await client.fetchCalendars();

const result = getBasicAuthHeaders({
    username: username,
    password: password,
});

const events = await fetchCalendarObjects({
    calendar: calendars[0],
    headers: result,
});
```

The problem though is that I can't write events. The library tsdav uses a put method to write events with the `createCalendarObject()` function. But SOGo allows no put methods.

I'm looking for a way to send a simple post request to `https://example.com/SOGo/dav/username/Calendar/personal/`, but I can't find an docs about endpoints or parameters.

Comment: Or are there some general mail endpoints to send requests to?